# Vidoes not play over HTTPS on old safari with angular

Tags: html, ios, angularjs, video

please help me !!!

I have a strange problem!
I have a project with angular 11 that plays videos in chrome browser on any device, but it is not working in safari browser in iPhone 6s with software version 12.3 and it works on above of this version like 13. problem is just on this version.

firstly I tried to a lot of solutions like change SSL cert and video player, but dont worked...
again I tried to test videos on another framework like vue.js and it plays fine !!

now I dont know exactly what is the problem??
is problem with angular? with https? with dependencies? with safari?

it is my package.json file

[image]

it is my code for display video:

```
   <div class="col-12 pt-2 pt-sm-0" [ngClass]="{ 'media_element' : mediaType === 'video'}">
    <video
    *ngIf="mediaType === 'video' "
    controls
    [src]="mediaDetail?.video"
    [poster]="mediaDetail?.cover"
    class="single_video"
    autoplay loop muted playsinline
    controlsList="nodownload">
  </video></div>
```

Comment: Can you please add the code on how you display the video?

Comment: @JacopoSciampi of course